# jQuery .grep() thread

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .grep function that excutes in a condition validation for example :

```
if(jQuery.grep(parameters, function( a ) {  return a.name == $("#param_name").val();})!="")
```

this will validate if $("param_name").val() which is an input val exists in some array .

what if i want to excute another operation to make sure that the value doesnt exist and in same time not equal to some value like

```
if(jQuery.grep(parameters, function( a ) {  return a.name == $("#param_name").val();})!="somevalue")
```

I dont want to run grep twice on same array using `&&` is there a neat way to do so ?!

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/AmPgJ/

i want this to alert match whenever you enter b or c but not a.

Comment: ofcourse is an array !! grep only works with arrays !!

Comment: can put all the logic you want inside the grep function, just need to return a boolean after it's all done

Comment: @charlietfl example please !

Comment: work up a simple demo in jsfiddle.net that gives more real world concept of what you want. Your criteria is still a bit vague

Comment: @charlietfl i have made a fiddle , hope it is clear now

Comment: doesn't seem you understand concept of grep. See if this helps  http://fiddle.jshell.net/AmPgJ/4/

Comment: correct me if im wrong , grep should filter an array and return matches in another array !! we can define a filter and i understand this , i think i just missed some point but got it now ty !

Comment: grep filters an array based on whatever logic you apply within the function to determine if array elements pass filter criteria, and returns new array. That's why I used length test in my demo.

Comment: also...out of respect to all us adults here...please lose the exclamation marks on every comment you make

Comment: FYI- can save yourself time using shorthand to create arrays and objects ..`var parameters=[{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name'c'}]`

Comment: im sorry if you find my ! offensive just a typo im used to , and thx for the hint , actually i was just making a fiddle so for me that is better for my eyes to detect errors than typing a one line declaration , accept my apology again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per others' comments:

```
if(jQuery.grep(parameters, function(a) {
  var val = $('#param_name').val()
  return a.name == val && a.name != somevalue
})
```

Comment: punund this will filter the value before returning it !! this is not what i need , i need to compare all values unfiltered !

Comment: @ProllyGeek if that's the case you haven't done your job to describe your issue in enough detail. Even this comment `compare all values unfiltered` is not clear what you mean

Comment: im doing a fiddle please wait

Comment: I am still not sure what task are you trying to solve, even less so that you need `grep` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick the && inside of the function that grep is calling.  That way grep only runs once.  You can further optimize by calling $("#param_name").val() only once within that function.

Comment: what do you mean by sticking && inside grep ? grep will return an array , and the function returns a value , the comparison is done inside IF !!

Comment: What punund wrote.  You want the function to contain all the logic so the if is only done once as well.